# Build error with VC6

Tags: visual-c++-6

When I build my application in VC6 IDE, I get this error:

```
--------------------Configuration: all - Win32 PRO Unicode Release--------------------
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error executing c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.

all.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I don't have any custom build commands, and this error is particular to this specific project only. Please help.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? If so, please make a comment as to how you fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Build error was due to the unload of one of our sub-project dsp in our VC dsp file.
We unloaded a sub project that was not required for build. but we didnt remove it from project dsp.
( actually we have series of sub - project dsp files to be built with the main dsp file)

Once it was loaded and built again, the error vanished. Thanks for your suggestions and answers.
Didnt get the reason, but it solved the problem.

Comment: My colleague found that this is not the solution, and the issue is stil open so this could not be answer,so this should not the accepted answer

Comment: The build actually consists of a pre-link step which actually has to copy a library, The library did not exist as such in the path and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you have a custom build command in one of your applications dependencies.

Review them all, and in each one that has anything, add an ECHO ON as the first step.
Then when you do your build, you will see the details of what command is failing.

The most common problem I have, is when i try to copy header files to a common location automatically.   I sometimes get the relative path wrong.   Adding a DIR to the post build
is an easy way to show where you are, and can help correct path errors.

Answer (score -1):

you may be deleted your environment variable

Comment: in environment variables (C:\WIndows\System32\cmd.exe) it is available.
And in Tools->Options->Directories->Executables

has the entry C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score -2):

I changed the build mode from from Win32 Simulation to Win32 Debug and clicked on "Rebuild All" and it worked.